# Short story about a man who claimed to be a time traveler, committed suicide, and claimed he instigated the holocaust

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I am trying to find the title and author of science fiction short story about a man who killed himself, who claimed to be a time traveler who'd traveled to the past to mitigate his version of WW2, only to instigate the holocaust.

Comment: Is this the story where Hitler hears the time traveler in his (Hitler's) head, and this makes Hitler think all Jews are out to get him, which leads to his paranoia of Jews and the holocaust?

Answer (score 7):

The story I'm thinking of is ["The Primal Solution"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50177) by Eric Norden ([text on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v053n01_1977-07_Lenny_Silv3r/page/n133), [summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Primal_Solution)).

In the story it is possible for someone to send their consciousness - but not their body - back in time using something like hypnotism.  The protagonist discovers this phenomenon in a patient and replicates it using lab equipment.  He decides he must try to kill Hitler before he can lead the Nazis to power, thus averting the holocaust.  He jumps into Hitler's mind, and takes control of his body, but before he can kill Hitler, Hitler regains control of his body.  Hitler has been aware while the time-traveler was in control and is left with the impression that this Jewish man hates him, and was trying to kill him on behalf of all the Jews.  The time-traveler realizes, as Hitler resolves to do something about the Jews to protect himself, that Hitler had not previously viewed Jewish people as a threat, and as a result, the time-traveler himself has planted the seed of the holocaust.

The story is told in the form of a letter to his present time, in which he explains his error, and expresses his sorrow for the deaths his action will cause.
The major discrepancy is that the time-traveler doesn't explicitly commit suicide; his abandoned body will die in the time he left, but the time-traveler's mind is trapped in Hitler's until Hitler's death.

Comment: Unfortunately, while that sounds interesting, and similar, I remember details of the story that don't match.

Comment: The time traveler went back to ameliorate the terrible treatment of the Jews in the Great War, but apparently his meddling made things far worse, resulting in our actual history. He's considered insane and in an asylum in NY, but uses an "unknown martial art" (this story predates Krav Maga by many years) to overpower his guards and throws himself out a window in anguish over what he's done.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a lot like *Guilt Trip* by Charles Sheffield, in the August 1987 *Analog*.

The central character, Jacob Lansdorf, is a time traveller from an alternate future where Germany won WW1, there was no Balfour Declaration and hence no State of Israel. He is a Zionist, and tries to change history to make the Jewish state come about.

He goes back to 1914 and makes a small but crucial change so that Von Kluck fails to take Paris, and in the end Germany loses. To his horror, though, he discovers that, while he now has his Jewish State, he has also caused the *Holocaust*, which on his timeline never took place. And he cannot undo what he has  done, because Henry Moseley, the scientist whose work led to the discovery of time travel, has been killed at Gallipoli,, which on his TL was never fought.

Needless to say, nobody believes his tale, and he is committed as obviously delusional. The story ends with his suicide (he throws himself off a building) and one of the doctors studying a photograph found on his person, showing some famous London buildings, but with the more modern ones around them all slightly different from the actual ones.

Comment: That sounds more like it. Thanks!

Comment: No prob. Incidentally this is the *second* time I have identified a story from this issue of ANALOG.  Many moons ago I answered an inquiry  which turned of to be Ray Brown's "Cobwebs".. If that weren't enough, there is also a nice little short by Poul Anderson. All in all, one of their best issues.